# How can I change the list separator in the formulas in MS Excel 2019?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I enter a formula `=MOD(ROW(),2)=0`, I get an error, but when the formula is like this `=MOD(ROW();2)=0` then it works.

So that, I prefer the `,` since it's widely used.

Comment: Change your regional settings

Comment: There are 2 options you need to check. 1. Region settings. 2. Excel System separator option.

Answer (score 2):

This method:

- Run *Control Panel > Region*
- Click "Additional settings..."
- Stay in the Numbers tab
- Set the "List separator" to your preferred separator
- Click OK twice.

Note: Setting it to comma only works if the "Decimal symbol"
is not also a comma.

Answer (score 0):

*There are two way to do this:*

Best one is to just change the sign to use as the list separator popular in your region.

You need to follow this:

- **C**ontrol Panel, **R**egion & Language , **A**dditional settings.
- Find **D**igit Grouping Symbol & Replace `;` with `,`.
- Finish with **O**k & better **R**estart computer.

---

*Another is Excel's built in settings:*

- **F**ile then **O**ptions then **A**dvanced.
- Find & use **S**ystem separators.
- Finish with **O**k & better reload the Excel.